# Angular mouseover and leave not working MAT-MENU

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a mat-sidenav and a list of mat-item and mat-menu. Then when I hover over of one of the items I want the menu to display. This part is working. But then when I move off of that menu or item and over a new item I want its menu to display.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsscrm

I have included a stackblitz with a demo of the behavior.

What is wrong here I have both on enter and exit, but then when I leave a menu on to a new one, it doesnt open unless I click on it.

Thanks for the help

Comment: The stackblitz included doesn't seem to include any of the hover behavior you mentioned.

Comment: @p4r1 that is correct, the when you move from one item to another its menu isnt shown, you have to click on it to see the menu, even though I have implemented `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

Comment: My previous comment's point was that the stackblitz in your question has no `mouseenter` or `mouseleave` logic in it. It looks like an unmodified sample taken from the material templates without any extra code.

Comment: @p4r1 posted wrong url, please check again

Comment: @SpencerFontein move the mouse leave event to the same level as mouse enter and it will work.  However, there is a funny animation that makes your resulting menu item 'slide about' before settling down.  Not sure what that is

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that when a menu opens, it creates an overlay with a backdrop that overlaps all elements. This backdrop is causing the mouse events to not be 'seen' by the listening element until the overlay is dismissed via a mouse click. Luckily, the menu control has a flag to remove the backdrop; setting this to false fixes the issue you're seeing.

Side note: you have an `*ngFor` on the `<mat-list>` element, but I think you want to move it to the `<mat-list-item>` element instead because you want many list items, not many lists. Since you're using the local variable of `*ngFor` outside of the `<mat-list-item>`, you can create an `<ng-container>` element to house your `*ngFor`. See below stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsscrm-kx6jyd

Another side note: this behavior is similar to a tooltip. Perhaps that would be a better control for your use-case? https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview